# Google spreadsheets API - Getting permanent access token

Tags: java, google-api, google-sheets

I've got a simple Java program that runs on my computer. Its only function is to read an online spreadsheet (which is **private** - say, a shopping list), then do some unrelated work on that.

Every since Google dropped OAuth1.0 this month, I've been trying to get the program to work with OAuth2. Previously, I could have the program authenticate using my email and an application password.

**Now**, I was forced to work through access tokens. My code:

```
package joeslist;

import com.google.gdata.client.spreadsheet.SpreadsheetService;
import com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.CellFeed;
import com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.SpreadsheetEntry;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeRequestUrl;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleTokenResponse;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.SpreadsheetFeed;
import com.google.gdata.util.ServiceException;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author 74
 */
public class JoesList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final String CLIENT_ID = "my_client_id.apps.googleusercontent.com";  //Unused?
        final String CLIENT_SECRET = "myClientSecret";

    // This is the Redirect URI for installed applications.
        // If you are building a web application, you have to set your
        // Redirect URI at https://code.google.com/apis/console.
        final String REDIRECT_URI = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob";

        final SpreadsheetService service;
        CellFeed feed;
        service = new SpreadsheetService("Joe's List");

        HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
        JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
        String[] SCOPESArray = {"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds"};
        final List SCOPES = Arrays.asList(SCOPESArray);
        GoogleCredential credential;

        try {          
            // Step 1: Authorize.
            String authorizationUrl = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeRequestUrl(CLIENT_ID, REDIRECT_URI, SCOPES).build();

            // Point or redirect your user to the authorizationUrl.
            System.out.println("Go to the following link in your browser:");
            System.out.println(authorizationUrl);

            // Read the authorization code from the standard input stream.
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            System.out.println("Paste the code that you got.");
            String code = in.readLine();
             // End of Step 1 <--

            // Step 2: Exchange!
            GoogleTokenResponse response
                    = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest(httpTransport, jsonFactory, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET,
                            code, REDIRECT_URI).execute();
            System.out.println("Token expires in: " + response.getExpiresInSeconds() + " seconds!"); 

            // Let's build our GoogleCredential now.
            credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                    .setClientSecrets(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET)
                    .setTransport(httpTransport)
                    .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
                    .build()
                    .setAccessToken(response.getAccessToken())
                    .setRefreshToken(response.getRefreshToken());       
            service.setOAuth2Credentials(credential);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FuckingTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        try {
            final String spreadsheetName = "Joe's sheet";
            final URL metafeedUrl=new URL("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full?xoauth_requestor_id=joe");
            final SpreadsheetFeed spreadsheetFeed = service.getFeed(metafeedUrl, SpreadsheetFeed.class);
            final List<SpreadsheetEntry> spreadsheets = spreadsheetFeed.getEntries();
            System.err.println(spreadsheets.size());
            for (final SpreadsheetEntry spreadsheet : spreadsheets) {
                System.err.println(spreadsheet.getTitle().getPlainText());
                if (spreadsheetName.equals(spreadsheet.getTitle().getPlainText())) {
                    System.err.println("Found the Spreadsheet you want.");
                }
            }
        } catch (final MalformedURLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (final IOException | ServiceException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }
}
```

---

### The problem:

This is a private little program. I will be its sole user and all I want it to do is read a private spreadsheet.

Will I have to jump through hoops every time I run it, manually copying and pasting the access token?
Is there any way I can get a long-lasting or permanent access token?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that you would have to go through this process every time your access token expires.

Access tokens have limited lifetimes which is correct from a security standpoint. A permanent access token is a security hole waiting to be discovered ( you know someone just forgot to encrypt it and ended up storing it under /var/log or worse on the Desktop).

**EDIT based on the comment from OP**

Google provides service accounts that allow server to server communications. More information is available at [Using OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount)

Comment: Any way to use a service account or anything like that to get acces to my private spreadsheet, and just read it?

I mean, I *AM* issuing the keys myself...

Comment: Updated my answer -  please check if this satisfies your requirements.